# C# Linq select and cast without error

Tags: c#, linq

is there a cleaner way to get a list of dogs that bark?

```
public abstract class Mammal
{
    public bool sweat_glands;
    public bool is_aquatic;
}
public class Whale: Mammal
{
    public Whale() { is_aquatic = true; }
}
public class Dog: Mammal
{
    public bool Barks { get; set; }
    public Dog() { is_aquatic = false; }
}
class Program
{        
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Mammal> mammals = new List<Mammal>();
        mammals.Add(new Whale());
        mammals.Add(new Dog() { Barks = false });
        List<Dog> dogs = (from c in mammals where c is Dog && ((Dog)c).Barks.Equals(true) select c).Cast<Dog>().ToList();
    }
}
```

if I do the following I get a compilation error on the last line: Multiple implementations of the query pattern were found for source type IEnumerable. Ambiguous call to Select.

```
List<Dog> dogs = (from c in mammals where c is Dog && ((Dog)c).Barks.Equals(true) select (Dog)c).ToList();
```

thanks!

Comment: This works fine for me. You could simplify it though: `dogs = mammals.OfType<Dog>().Where(d => d.Barks).ToList();`

Comment: Just a note: do not use `ToList()` unless you *really need* to  have the `List<T>`. Remember: it allocates a whole new array.

Comment: If [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/355) or one of its spinoffs is realistic and ever gets done, `from c in mammals where c is Dog d && d.Barks select d` should become possible. But that is not today.

Comment: I don't know why I was getting the error, I re-created the project and it worked fine, thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 5):

Your code works fine for me. You could simplify it using [`OfType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var dogs = mammals
    .OfType<Dog>()
    .Where(d => d.Barks);
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to do the whole thing on one line, it can get confusing.

```
List<Dog> dogs = (from c in mammals 
                  let d = (c as Dog)
                  where 
                     d != null && d.Barks
                  select d
                 ).ToList();
```